# How to see files of a zip and their contents using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, zip

How can I read the contents of files in a ZIP file using Javascript? Is there a NPM module that can offer this functionality or is there a method without using any NPM modules?

Im trying to make a Plugin system for a app, and the zips have 2 files: index.js - main plugin code and manifest.json - author name, plugin name, etc.

Comment: Google is your friend for those kind of questions. You'll find lots of packages. Also, those packages are all implemented using Node.js so yes you could do it yourself. That's pretty much always the case. In case of a package it's just that someone has done the work for you and offers it to you for free. It's always your choice whether to use a package or not. One example is [adm-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip). In case of working with .zip file you probably don't want to do it yourself as there are (complex) compression algorithms involved.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js has built-in functionality to unzip file contents with `Zlib` using [zlib.createUnzip()](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlibcreateunzipoptions).